# What is implied by these UPS related messages?

Tags: ups

I am using ubuntu12.04 and have apc ups connected through usb. I have apcupsd (3.14.10) installed. Recently I have started getting messages on terminal like these:

---

Broadcast Message from root@desktop
        (somewhere) at 17:17 ...                                                            Communications restored with UPS BACK-UPS-ES500"

---

The log file has these additional messages:

---

Oct 25 17:17:34 desktop kernel: [ 1192.920049] hub 3-0:1.0: port 1 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...

Oct 25 17:17:34 desktop kernel: [ 1192.920059] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 5

Oct 25 17:17:34 desktop kernel: [ 1193.160025] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd

Oct 25 17:17:35 desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1"

Oct 25 17:17:35 desktop mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device

Oct 25 17:17:35 desktop kernel: [ 1193.969232] generic-usb 0003:051D:0002.0005: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [American Power Conversion Back-UPS ES 500 FW:850.m3.I USB FW:m3] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0

Oct 25 17:17:41 desktop apcupsd[1133]: Communications with UPS restored.

---

Can anybody please explain what problem is indicated and what I should do about it?

Other details: if I use the commands: "sudo service apcupsd stop" and then "sudo apctest" the result is:

---

Clearing previous self test result...CLEARED

Initiating self test...INITIATED

Waiting for test to complete...ERROR READING STATUS

25.876 apcupsd: linux-usb.c:784 HIDIOCGREPORT for function SelftestStatus failed. ERR=No such device

---

surprisingly if I use the apctest command again, the result is:

---

Clearing previous self test result...CLEARED

Initiating self test...INITIATED

Waiting for test to complete...COMPLETED

Result of last self test: PASSED

---

Now what do I do about the message appearing on the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bad USB-port or a bad USB-cable. It should not just disconnect for no reason.

1. Try changing the USB-port on your PC.
2. Try another USB-cable.